# Redirecting output appends (decimal) point. Why?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, echo

I work remotly on a Ubuntu 14.04.1 with bash 4.3.11(1) and noticed something I can't find an explanation for:

If I try like

```
$echo foo
```

The output is

```
foo
```

No surprise here. But if I try

```
$echo foo > file.txt
```

the content of file.txt is

```
foo.
```

(notice the period at the end.)

I didn't find anything about it and it's not quite easy to google information about a ">" and a ".". What's going on here?

Comment: How do you display the contents of file.txt? Just cat, or in an editor? UTF issue? Line ending? Perhaps the dot is a placeholder for carriage return? Check the contents of file.txt with a hex editor.

Comment: No clue in your information. Is your echo an alias? Do you have `set -o noclobber`? In `$echo`, is $ your command-prompt?  What happens when you append foo again `echo foo >> file.txt`, do you get 2 times `foo.`?

Comment: Also include the output of `type echo` in your question and maybe `which echo`.

Comment: Thank you for your questions and hints.

The period seems to appear only in the internal viewer of Total Commander as representation of the line wrap (x0A). So it's it's fault.
(Strangely it doesn't show any period after adding a second line,l ike you suggested @Walter. Although the linewraps of course are there.)

So thank you again.

(What am I supposed to do now with my stupid question? 0:-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: 
With the comments Robin found the answer (Total Commander issue) and can accept an answer now.